# python twisted stdio example on windows doesn't work

Tags: python, twisted

I started playing with python/twisted but when I test [the stdin example](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/core/examples/stdin.py) on Windows from `cmd.exe`, the example doesn't work.  I'm using python 2.7 and twisted 12.1.0 (binary msi package).  I hoped it was a buffering problem, so I tried also running the script with "python -u stdin.y", but nothing changed.

Obviously, this script works on Linux and on OS X.

Answer (score 5):

There is [already an open Twisted ticket to make `twisted.internet.stdio` work on the console in Windows](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/2157).  There's even a fair amount of code associated with this ticket, and a huge amount of diagnosis.

In short, the Windows command-line is a huge mess. It's not even that it's a different interface than the POSIX standard command line; it's a completely different *kind* of thing.  On Linux or OS X, the console is like a tiny, fake teletype that you send bytes and control codes to.  On Windows, the console is more like a tiny, fake computer running DOS that you write to the video memory of.

Nevertheless, feel free to help out on that ticket!  It could use some more interest!

Comment: Possibly the most accurate description of Windows consoles I've ever heard.