# Python Twisted addReader works in linux but not windows

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to write a client in python 2.7 using Twisted. My code works just fine in linux (debian squeeze), but when I tried it on windows (xp and 7) I got a constant stream of error messages. A screenshot of these messages is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2CFm.png).

I have narrowed down the bug and was able to write a very stripped down version of my client that still contains the bug:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol,ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TheClient(LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self,line):
        print line

    def connectionLost(self,reason):
        reactor.stop()

class TheFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = TheClient

class Test(object):
    def doRead(self):
        pass

    def fileno(self):
        return 0

    def connectionLost(self,reason):
        print 'connection lost'

    def logPrefix(self):
        return 'Client'

def main():
    print 'starting'
    test = Test()
    reactor.addReader(test)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the line containing 'reactor.addReader(test)' is commented out, I do not get any error messages. If I run this code on linux without commenting out any lines, I do not get any error messages.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443040/python-twisted-stdio-example-on-windows-doesnt-work), I don't think its the same problem, but as expected, it did not function properly on windows.

Is this code correct, and this is a windows bug, or do I have to do things differently for it to work in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows implementation of `select` only supports sockets.  Presumably file descriptor 0 in your process does not represent a socket.  More likely it represents something related to standard I/O.

If you'd just like to use standard I/O, then there's `twisted.internet.stdio`, though you may run into some rough edges with it on Windows (bug reports and fixes appreciated!).

If you're not interested in standard I/O and 0 was just an arbitrary test, you'll probably need to decide on what kind of input you're trying to do in particular.  Depending on what kind of file descriptor you have, there will probably be a different approach to successfully reading from it.

Comment: I am trying to read IO, specifically I'm using curses and, according to [this file](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/core/examples/cursesclient.py?rev=24576), the fileno function should return 0 (sys.stdin.fileno() == 0). Like I said in the question, this is working for me in linux, but it sounds like windows select only supporting sockets is probably the problem.

Comment: Yes.  You cannot read from standard input using `SelectReactor.addReader` on Windows.

Comment: That is not your only problem.  The ncurses module isn't available on Windows, so even if you got this working it wouldn't help.  See http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#module-curses - it says "Platforms: Unix".

Comment: @Glyph I am aware that the curses module is not officially available on Windows. There are however unofficial ones that work.